# Is there a way to arrange multiple windows in one window?

Tags: window-management

I want something like terminator, but not only for terminals, but for any gui apps. Is there anything like this?

May be a tiling wm in a window. Google suggests I can use Xnest or Xephyr to do that. I think that launching a new X server just to arrange windows is a little bit too much, but if there is no simpler solution, then I will use this one.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can run a window manager as a non-root window that might act _as_ a root window to things running within it.

Comment: What do you mean by “multiple windows in a window”? (I don't use Terminator, so “something like terminator” is completely uninformative.) What does this change from just placing a bunch of windows next to each other? Is this about moving and resizing them as a group in some way? About having them appear on the same desktop?

Comment: "Is this about moving and resizing them as a group in some way?" Yes, exactly